# Difference between the Central EventBus and Backbone.Radio?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, event-bus

In the context of `Backbone.js` and `Marionette.js`, what is the difference between the `Central EventBus` and the `Backbone.Radio` system? Does the `Backbone.Radio` system wrap the `Central EventBus`?

Comment: What do you mean by `Central EventBus`? Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `App.vent` in Marionette v2.. then Radio can be shimmed in so that `App.vent` uses Radio in it's implementation.

However the events object on the App was removed in v3.  Rather than having a single events object on the application and scoping events by a naming convention, we recommend using radio channels.  You can still attach a radio channel to the Marionette.Application if you want to treat it like `App.vent` but it is no longer implemented this way for you.  In general, if needed, I would recommend using Radio directly.